# Function not working from particular context in angular

Tags: angularjs, highcharts, ng-grid

I'm having problem with context when context when calling a function attached to `$scope`.

I'm trying to setup two way interaction between ngGrid and highcharts. I can click on a row in ngGrid and select the partner column in highcharts but not visa versa. I can select a row in ngGrid via a button of the same scope but not via highcharts.

Please take a look at: http://plnkr.co/edit/z14LDp?p=preview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a call to scope.$apply() you shoud modify your highlights click function and it would work nicely

```
 click: function (event) {
              $scope.selectRow(this.data.indexOf(event.point));
               $scope.$apply();
            }
```